# How to get custom field value of taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have added a custom field to taxonomy called avatar actor

[image]

[image]

How can I display it in my post?

```
<?php 
    $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
    $taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
    $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
    
    $actor_avatar = get_field('actor_avatar', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
    $actor_eng_name = get_field('actor_english_name', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
    $actor_dob = get_field('actor_dob', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
    $actor_nation = get_field('actor_nation', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
    $actor_job = get_field('actor_job', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
    $actor_blood = get_field('actor_blood', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
    $actor_forte = get_field('actor_forte', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
    $actor_interests = get_field('actor_interests', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
    $actor_height = get_field('actor_height', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
    $actor_weight = get_field('actor_weight', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
    $actor_gender = get_field('actor_gender', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
    $actor_info = get_field('actor_info', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `get_the_terms` and `get_field`. check the below code.

```
<?php 

global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_object = $term;
    break;
}

$actor_avatar    = get_field('actor_avatar', $term_object);
$actor_eng_name  = get_field('actor_english_name', $term_object);
$actor_dob       = get_field('actor_dob', $term_object);
$actor_nation    = get_field('actor_nation', $term_object);
$actor_job       = get_field('actor_job', $term_object);
$actor_blood     = get_field('actor_blood', $term_object);
$actor_forte     = get_field('actor_forte', $term_object);
$actor_interests = get_field('actor_interests', $term_object);
$actor_height    = get_field('actor_height', $term_object);
$actor_weight    = get_field('actor_weight', $term_object);
$actor_gender    = get_field('actor_gender', $term_object);
$actor_info      = get_field('actor_info', $term_object);

?>
```